# postgres interval add variable current_setting not work

Tags: postgresql

```
set session myconstants.test =  '10';
set session myconstants.testb =  '10 min';
SELECT now()::time - interval concat (current_setting('myconstants.selfName')::varchar,' min');
SELECT now()::time - INTERVAL '10 min';
set session myconstants.test =  '10';
SELECT now()::time - interval current_setting('myconstants.testb')::varchar;
SELECT now()::time - INTERVAL '10 min';
```

i want add variable in interval function,but current_setting not work..how could i solve it?i use postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the variable value to an interval:

```
SELECT now()::time - current_setting('myconstants.testb')::interval
```

The prefix notation `interval '....'` **only** works with constants following it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try make_interval.

```
SET session myconstants.test = 10;

SELECT
    now() + make_interval(mins => current_setting('myconstants.test')::int);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution,[operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer in PostgreSql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264628/operator-does-not-exist-timestamp-with-time-zone-integer-in-postgresql).

```
create function addit(timestamptz,int) returns timestamptz immutable language sql as $$
    select $1+ interval '1 hour'*$2
$$;
create operator + (leftarg =timestamptz, rightarg =int, procedure=addit);

create function minusit(timestamptz,int) returns timestamptz immutable language sql as $$
    select $1+ interval '-1 hour'*$2
$$;
create operator - (leftarg =timestamptz, rightarg =int, procedure=minusit);
```

create + and - operator ,and execute

```
set session myconstants.testb =  -1;
select start_time ,start_time - current_setting('myconstants.testb')::integer  from besoccer_team bt ;
select start_time ,start_time - current_setting('myconstants.testb')::integer  from besoccer_team bt ;
```

start_time is timestamp type

```
set session myconstants.testb =  -1;
select  now()::timestamp  , now()::timestamp  - current_setting('myconstants.testb')::integer  from besoccer_team bt ;
select  now()::timestamp  , now()::timestamp  - current_setting('myconstants.testb')::integer  from besoccer_team bt ;
```